# Rotate object around a center object

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi guys I wrote this code to rotate an object around a center object but I am doing somthing wrong could someone explain me what :)?

```
public void RotateCamera(GameObject _center)
{
    Vector3 mousePos = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector3 centerPos = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(_center.transform.position);
    float angle = Vector3.Angle(centerPos,mousePos);
    Camera.mainCamera.transform.Rotate(centerPos,angle);
}
```

Updated code still doesnt work:

```
void Update()
{
RotateCamera(_player);
}

public void RotateCamera(GameObject _center)
{
    float speedMod = 10.0f;
    Vector3 mousePos = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector3 centerPos = _center.transform.position;
    Camera.mainCamera.transform.LookAt(centerPos);
    Camera.mainCamera.transform.RotateAround (centerPos,mousePos,20 * Time.deltaTime * speedMod);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if what you want to do is rotate camera around a object

```
 public TargetClass target;//the target object
    private float speedMod = 10.0f;//a speed modifier
    private Vector3 point;//the coord to the point where the camera looks at

    void Start () {//Set up things on the start method
        point = target.transform.position;//get target's coords
        transform.LookAt(point);//makes the camera look to it
    }

    void Update () {//makes the camera rotate around "point" coords, rotating around its Y axis, 20 degrees per second times the speed modifier
        transform.RotateAround (point,new Vector3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f),20 * Time.deltaTime * speedMod);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but it needs to see the angle between the mouse position and the target. So if I click on the right side of the object it will rotate right or if I click on the left side of the object it will rotate left. This code doesnt do that right?

Comment: O wait can I replace the vector3 in the rotateAround for the mouse position?

Comment: the `RotateAround` must be in `Update`

Comment: Huh? Why should the RotateAround be in the update because the entire function gets updated so the RotateAround also?

Comment: Because you need to call this function every update. It is not thread or loop like function to rotate everytime when invoked. So you need to call it every update.